# How to update a document only if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to implement a put method in a express API in order to allow the user to update a document, but only if a condition is met. Let's say I have an `Instance` document. One of its attributes is `executed`, which can be `true` if the instance was execute or `false` if it wasn't. Basically I want to allow the user to update this document only if the instance hasn't been executed, it is, if the `executed` attribute is false.

I've come up with this approach, but I'd like to know whether there is a better approach to do it, for instance, using the `pre` function in the schema definition.

```
Instance.findOne({'_id': req.params.id}, function(err, element){
    if(!element.executed){
        Instance.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req.params.id}, {$set: req.body}, function(err, element){
            ...
        });
    }
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the single document, you can use:

```
Instance.findOneAndUpdate({
  '_id': req.params.id,
  executed: false
}, req.body, {
  new: true
}, (err, instance) => {
  if(err){
    console.error('error occurred', err);
  } else {
    console.log('updated instance', instance)
  }
});
```

`{new: true}` will return the updated instance.

For more detail please check the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty intuitive and cleaner than my solution. I'm accepting your answer because you provided more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use update method,

```
Instance.update({'_id': req.params.id, executed: false}, req.body, function(){})
```

Comment: in case of multiple records use {multi: true } as 3rd parameter